# insert an element in binary search tree gives stopped working

Tags: c, if-statement, memory-management, binary-search-tree

When I call insert(element) function and add element, it gives an error as programme has stopped working.
It gives an error when i add 3rd element in left of root or add an element in right side of root.

please help to solve it.

```
 void insert(int iElement){
        if(sRoot==NULL){         //Initially sRoot is NULL
            sRoot=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            sRoot->iData=iElement;
            sRoot->sLeft=NULL;
            sRoot->sRight=NULL;
        }
        else{
            struct Node *current=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            current->iData=iElement;
            current->sLeft=NULL;
            current->sRight=NULL;
            struct Node *parent;
            struct Node *temp;
            parent=sRoot;
            while(parent!=NULL){
                temp=parent;
                if(iElement>parent->iData){
                    parent=parent->sRight;
                }
                if(iElement<parent->iData){
                    parent=parent->sLeft;
                }
            }
            if(iElement<temp->iData)
                temp->sLeft=current;
            else
                temp->sRight=current;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two bugs in the function the first is that in the loop there are used two if statements instead of if-else if statements.

```
    while(parent!=NULL){
        temp=parent;
        if(iElement>parent->iData){
            parent=parent->sRight;
        }
        if(iElement<parent->iData){
            parent=parent->sLeft;
        }
    }
```

So if the first if statement was executed then `parent` can be set to `NULL`. However in the second statement you are trying to access the data member `iData` for such a `NULL` pointer.

So there must be at least

```
    while(parent!=NULL){
        temp=parent;
        if(iElement>parent->iData){
            parent=parent->sRight;
        }
        else if(iElement<parent->iData){
            parent=parent->sLeft;
        }
    }
```

The second problem with this loop is if the used will supply a duplicate value then this loop will be infinite because the pointer `parent` is not changed.

Also there will be a memory leak because the memory was already allocated for the pointer `current` though neither node shall be appended in case of a duplicate value.

So you need to process the case when the user supplied a duplicate value.

The function can be implemented the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int iData;
    struct Node *sLeft;
    struct Node *sRight;
};

struct Node *sRoot = NULL;

int insert( int iElement )
{
    int success = 1;
    struct Node **current = &sRoot;

    while ( success && *current != NULL )
    {
        if ( iElement < ( *current )->iData )
        {
            current = &( *current )->sLeft;
        }
        else if ( ( *current )->iData < iElement )
        {
            current = &( *current )->sRight;
        }
        else
        {
            success = 0;
        }
    }

    if ( success )
    {
        *current = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
        success = *current != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            ( *current )->iData = iElement;
            ( *current )->sLeft = NULL;
            ( *current )->sRight = NULL;
        }
    }

    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{

    insert( 10 );
    insert( 9 );
    insert( 11 );
    insert( 12 );
    insert( 8 );
    insert( 7 );

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that it is a bad idea when a function depends on global variables.

So it is better to declare it like with one more parameter

```
int insert( struct Node **sRoot, int iElement );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified one, explaination I kept in comments.

```
void insert(int iElement){
        if(sRoot==NULL){         //Initially sRoot is NULL
                sRoot=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
                sRoot->iData=iElement;
                sRoot->sLeft=NULL;
                sRoot->sRight=NULL;
        }
        else{
                struct Node *current=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
                current->iData=iElement;
                current->sLeft=NULL;
                current->sRight=NULL;
                struct Node *parent;
                struct Node *temp;
                parent=sRoot;
                while(parent!=NULL){ /* it fails when parent is NULL */
                        if(iElement > parent->iData){
                                if(parent->sRight ! = NULL)/* need to check if parent->right is null or not */
                                        parent->sRight = current;/*if not NULL then put i
t here */
                                else
                                        parent = parent->sRight;/* update the parent */
                        }
                        if(iElement < parent->iData){
                                if(parent->sLeft ! = NULL)
                                        parent->sLeft = current;
                                else
                                        parent=parent->sLeft;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: I am already taking "temp=parent" and use temp pointer in outside the loop.

Comment: where you are checking this `parent->sRight ! = NULL` ? you have to check `parent->sRight` is empty or  not. Also No need to take `temp`.

Comment: ok got it.thanks...my programme is also correct if i use " else if " instead of " if " in loop as i realized later.

Comment: @VedantPatel If my answer helped you, you should accept the answer.